# State pattern behavior in javascript clarification

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code provided by chat gpt api, i have been self studying and understanding its generated code, but this time im having trouble, I would like to seek assistance for the experts.

here is the generate code

```
class State {
  constructor(player) {
    this.player = player;
  }
}

class PlayingState extends State {
  play() {
    console.log('Music is already playing');
  }

  pause() {
    console.log('Pausing music');
    this.player.setState(new PausedState(this.player));
  }

  stop() {
    console.log('Stopping music');
    this.player.setState(new StoppedState(this.player));
  }
}

class PausedState extends State {
  play() {
    console.log('Resuming music');
    this.player.setState(new PlayingState(this.player));
  }

  pause() {
    console.log('Music is already paused');
  }

  stop() {
    console.log('Stopping music');
    this.player.setState(new StoppedState(this.player));
  }
}

class MusicPlayer {
  constructor() {
    this._state = new StoppedState(this);
  }

  setState(state) {
    this._state = state;
  }

  play() {
    this._state.play();
  }

  pause() {
    this._state.pause();
  }

  stop() {
    this._state.stop();
  }
}

class StoppedState extends State {
  play() {
    console.log('Music playing.');
    this.player.setState(new PlayingState(this.player));
  }

  pause() {
    console.log("Can't pause. Music is not playing.");
  }

  stop() {
    console.log('Music is already stopped');
  }
}

// Usage
const player = new MusicPlayer();

player.play(); // Output: Music playing
player.pause(); // Output: Pausing music
player.play();
```

I'm having a confusion on StoppedState class part, under play method.
As you can see there, the code is this.player.setState(new PlayingState(this.player))

my number one question is, how come that the player has an setState method ? wherein if i navigate to that, its reference is State class with no setState method. the set state method is under MusicPlayer, how come it has setState method ? it has something to do with referencing in javascript ? how come ?

my next question is this part new PlayingState(this.player) under the same table, in PlayingState
why this.player is passing to the constructor ? i get it because it extending state class and it has a player constructor, but my main issue is what is the value or data or what this.player contains to be exact upon passing to playing state.

Thankyou folks, i just studying and i want it to understand deeply, whats happening in the code

addition, also tried asking chat gpt about this one like i ask, but he keeps saying

I apologize for the mistake. You are correct, the this._player object does not have a setState function. That function needs to be defined in the MusicPlayer class for the code to work correctly:

thats why I desperately ask here. to hear some guide from expert

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it have a `setState` method? It's defined in the class. `State` has a `MusicPlayer`, `MusicPlayer` has a `setState`. Now: whether or not this design is **good** is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: It's a **Really Bad Idea** to self-study JavaScript from code generated from an AI at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you'd want to ask chatGPT to write some code and then try to understand this code...

In any case, here's what's going on:

In the line `const player = new MusicPlayer();`, a new `MusicPlayer` instance is created and stored in the `player` constant.
When this instance is created, its constructor is run and so this line is run `this.state = new StoppedState(this);`.
Since we're in the MusicPlayer's constructor, `this` is the current instance and we pass it to the constructor of `StoppedState`.
`StoppedState` extends `State` so the constructor of `State` is run, which causes this line to run `this.player = player;`.
The `player` here is a reference to the same `MusicPlayer` instance we created and so it is stored in the `player` property of the `StoppedState`.
At this point, all constructors have finished and you have an instance of `MusicPlayer` with a property called `_state` which contains a `StoppedState` instance with a property called `player` that holds a reference to the `MusicPlayer` instance.

When the line `player.play()` is run, this line `this._state.play();` is executed in the `MusicPlayer` class for the current instance.
This in turn executes this line `console.log('Music playing.');` and this line `this.player.setState(new PlayingState(this.player));` from the `StoppedState` class instance we have stored in the `MusicPlayer` instance.
The later line calls the `setState` function that is part of the `MusicPlayer` instance that is stored on the state, passing `new PlayingState(this.player)` as a parameter.
The code `new PlayingState(this.player)` creates a new instance of the `PlayingState` class that extends the state class and passes along the same reference to the `MusicPlayer` instance, which is stored in the `player` property of the new `PlayingState` instance.
The `setState` function stores the resulting `PlayingState` instance in the `_state` property of the `MusicPlayer` instance.

The same goes for both the `pause` and `stop` functions.

As you can see, only one instance is created for the `MusicPlayer` class and new instances are created for the different states. Each time a new state is created, the reference to the current instance of the `MusicPlayer` class is stored inside it.